# How to construct a function from a pair of possibly empty sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on an elementary proof on the cardinality of sets on the following point:

Given two possibly empty sets, $A$ and $B$, I need to prove the existence of any function $f:A\rightarrow B$. Is it possible? Perhaps using AC? I'm thinking you must have at least a non-empty $B$ (all elements of $A$ mapped to the same point). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

With the issue of possibly empty sets $A, B$, you might want to read up a bit on the existence of the [**Empty function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_function).

> In mathematics, an empty function is a function whose domain is the empty set. For each set A, there is exactly one such empty function

$$f_A: \varnothing \rightarrow A.$$

> The graph of an empty function is a subset of the Cartesian product ∅ × A. Since the product is empty the only such subset is the empty set ∅. The empty subset is a valid graph since for every x in the domain ∅ there is a unique y in the codomain A such that (x,y) ∈ ∅ × A. This statement is an example of a vacuous truth since there is no x in the domain.

For perhaps a better explanation than that provided by Wikipedia, read this earlier post:

- [Why is the empty function considered a
  function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45625/why-is-an-empty-function-considered-a-function/45878#45878).
- See also: [Does there exist a bijection between empty
  sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140879/does-there-exist-a-bijection-between-empty-sets)

Comment: That makes sense. What about $f:A\rightarrow \varnothing$? That doesn't seem possible for non-empty $A$.

Comment: That's a good question. Regarding your "choice" question, you might want to visit [Axiom of Choice](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~schectex/ccc/choice.html)

Comment: You are absolutely correct, @Dan. If $A$ is non-empty, then there exists no function $A\to\varnothing.$ This corresponds to the fact that $0^{\mathfrak a}=0$ for any non-zero cardinal $\mathfrak a$.

Comment: @amWhy: nice guidance! =1

Comment: Dan, you are absolutely right that for $f: A \to B$, we need only stipulate that $B$ is not empty if A is not empty to guarantee the existence of a function from $f$.